# Targeted Content based on User Group

Tags: 2013, smarttarget

We would like to deliver (show) the content on pages based on User Groups created in SDL Tridion and in a DD4T enabled website. I have done it earlier for a non-DD4T site and is using a custom code in earlier 2009 era.

Now I have read through that many options are available:

- I can use  Target Group Feature of SDL Tridion 2013
- I can use the Tridion SCD (Secure Content Delivery) - Not sure if 2013 compatible version is available (Request already pending for same with Support)
- I can use Smart Target (We are anyway going to use Smart Target)
- I can use absolute custom code (I am not preferring it)

My question is that:

1. Can I use Smart target to personalize my content based on User Groups seamless (actually want to check if there is any catch in that)
2. Can expert share their views on above options from their experience?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If SmartTarget is an option, then I'd definitely go for it. This is probably the easiest integration point.

This is +/- what you'd have to do:

1. Create an ADF cartridge that reads the user's group memberships and adds this as an ADF claim (perhaps in a comma separated list?)
2. Configure trigger-types.xml to use this claim
3. Create promotions that trigger if the claim contains a group name

There might be an even simpler way to do it than using "contains", but top-of-my-head I think this would work and be quite scalable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nuno; I am also inclined towards this approach the only thing that I was wondering - Not only promotions but even navigations, text section/images/video etc. are delivered/shown on page as per the specific group :)
Thanks for giving a complete details for Smart Target.

Comment: Do you have any comments on Tridion SCD?